# Difference between browserTarget & devServerTarget in angular.json

Tags: angular, user-interface, cypress, angular-builder

Could not find enough information in Angular Documentation & would like to know the difference between

> **browserTarget** & **devServerTarget**

that is so frequently used in angular.json.

Below is the sample angular.json from a sample project.

```
...
"projects": {
  "myProject": {
    ...
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          ...
        },
        "configurations": {
          "development": {
            ...
          },
          "e2e": {
            ...
          }
        }
      },
      "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
        "options": {
          "browserTarget": "myProject:build:development",
          "proxyConfig": "./src/proxy.config.json",
        },
      },
      "e2e-ci": {
        "builder": "@cypress/schematic:cypress",
        "options": {
          "devServerTarget": "myProject:serve:e2e"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```